# VBA macro to export chart to image

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having an error with exporting charts to image on my VBA script. What I'm doing is exporting as images and sending them in emails as report. However, there's a 50/50 chance some charts get exported properly, and others just show as empty files.

```
Sub Emailer()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.Calculate
DoEvents
Application.Calculate

Application.Calculate
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next

    Sheets("Reporting Sheet").ChartObjects("Chart 3").Chart.Export "C:\Users\JudaL\Desktop\Reporting\1.png"
    Sheets("Reporting Sheet").ChartObjects("Chart 5").Chart.Export "C:\Users\JudaL\Desktop\Reporting\2.png"
    Sheets("Reporting Sheet").ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.Export "C:\Users\JudaL\Desktop\Reporting\3.png"
    Sheets("Reporting Sheet").ChartObjects("Chart 7").Chart.Export "C:\Users\JudaL\Desktop\Reporting\4.png"
    Sheets("Reporting Sheet").ChartObjects("Chart 10").Chart.Export "C:\Users\JudaL\Desktop\Reporting\5.png"
    Sheets("Reporting Sheet").ChartObjects("Chart 11").Chart.Export "C:\Users\JudaL\Desktop\Reporting\6.png"

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
        .To = "Test"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Test"
        .HTMLBody = "<img src='C:\Users\JudaL\Desktop\Reporting\1.png' />" & "<img src='C:\Users\JudaL\Desktop\Reporting\2.png' />" & "<img src='C:\Users\JudaL\Desktop\Reporting\3.png' />" & "<img src='C:\Users\JudaL\Desktop\Reporting\4.png' />" & "<img src='C:\Users\JudaL\Desktop\Reporting\5.png' />" & "<img src='C:\Users\JudaL\Desktop\Reporting\6.png' />"



        .Display   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Wait for disk operations will complete. `Sleep(lngYourTime): DoEvemts`

Comment: Are you sure about the chart names?

Comment: @ Larry - remove the On Error Resume Next, what happens?